# Let a program (called by other program) run as admin without prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, administrator, privileges, steam

As you may know, Steam doesn't like non-admin accounts for installing games or whatsoever. In my case, I have a user in my computer that usually install a lot of games and every time I have to put my password to successfully play or install them. Blame /bin/SteamService.exe.

I came up with a solution: [using RunAs to make Steam run as the admin user](http://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/13q5hb/let_steam_run_with_admin_rights_and_install_games/). But that is a potential security risk. So instead of that, I'm asking if is possible to do the following:

**Hot to grant SteamService.exe high trust levels (or admin privileges) automatically when Steam calls it?**

That way he can play and install games in Steam leaving the rest of the system alone. I don't mind if the user has to click "yes or no", but without prompt its better because some games asks every time they're executed.

Comment: SteamService already runs using your LocalSystem account - you can check this by looking at the service properties in Control Panel-> Services under the Logon tab. So not sure how this will help solve your problem.

Comment: In fact, this may be by design to allow the service to install software even if started by a user mode steam.exe process.

Comment: Thought that it was the case, but it is not. Even if its working as a Service, Steam uses a parameter when runs SteamService.exe to install software. It's like calling a new instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this is a game specific issue. I've seen this happen on Shogun 2:TW, Empire:TW, and Napoleon:TW. But not Dungeons and Dungeons: Dark Lord.

Perhaps it helps to know what games being used?

Comment: Payday, and some others I can't remember. But hell, they play them  all the time.